# Online and Chat in AppEngine Application

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an AppEngine application which uses Google Accounts as authentication. What is the approach or idea on seeing if someone is online or using the application? And able to chat to online users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official way to implement chat on App Engine is using the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview).  However, the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Channel) are strange, and it's fairly expensive at [$0.01/100 connections](http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/appengine/pricing.html).

I would recommend using a hosted web socket service like [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com), or running your own nodejs server on another host.

Comment: The Channel API would let you send a chat message from your Google App Engine instances to a browser.  You can also use it to check if someone who's on your page has disconnected.  However, you will need the XMPP API if you want to check if a GMail user is online, or to send a message to a GMail user.  If you want to implement your own chat client in a browser that can talk to other GMail users, you will need to use a combination of both APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XMPP API to get users status, and send them messages that appear in Google Chat.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/